# Rewrite a URL using a fake folder w/ the name of an existing PHP file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect any url like www.mysite.com/members/batman to www.mysite.com/infos.php?name=batman
I tried the following htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^members/([\w\.]+)/?$ infos.php?nom=$1 [L]
```

However, as the file members.php exists, that's the file I get (instead of infos.php).

Indeed, there is this default rule (which does not appear in the htaccess) redirecting any folder name (like "members") to the corresponding php file ("members.php") if the folder does not exist.

Ideally, I would like to have "members" as an exception to this rule. How could I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing my question down helped me to find some new keywords, and it led me to the following solution :

```
Options -MultiViews
```

This way, the folder names which do not exist are not redirected to the corresponding php files. It was funny to see that many people seem to look for this solution. It might be simpler if this "multiviews" option was disabled by default.